# OpenCV4 on XCode — opencv2/core.hpp not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

so I've been trying to install OpenCV with C++ on my mac using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@jaskaranvirdi/setting-up-opencv-and-c-development-environment-in-xcode-b6027728003 but I keep getting this error on Xcode:

[" 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcSO7.png)

I tried setting both Library Search Paths and Header Search Paths to recursive but it didn't change anything

I've also been getting this error on the terminal, I don't know if it's related. I think it's important to note that this isn't my first time trying to install opencv and I don't know if it's the old versions that keep messing with it. I tried to cleanup everything before installing this version but I'm not sure.

```css
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-55ed98.o
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in main-55ed98.o
      cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&) in main-55ed98.o
  "cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      cv::String::String(char const*) in main-55ed98.o
  "cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-55ed98.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve these issues please?

Comment: Setting up OpenCV on a mac can be a pain I ran into this issue multiple times and it was caused by using the incorrect flags for either the Library Search Path or the Header Search Path.

Comment: @yuRa if you mean the linker flags, I copied them directly from the output of the `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` command from the terminal!